# Is there a name for the set of unique combinations of numbers of a set for a given combination depth?

Tags: permutations, terminology, combinations

For example, the set of integers 1 to 3 with a depth of 1 the combinations would be.

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

While the combinations for the same set for a depth of 2 would be

```
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,1]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[3,1]
[3,2]
[3,3]
```

It's is not quite a permutation, as the number can be reused.

Comment: Perhaps multisets are what mean?  Edit: just saw the order matters. Then I guess you could call it an ordered multiset, sorry I do not know an exact term for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to the recent question [Name of $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$ in terms of $\{1,2,3\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3651749/26369), but you're asking for names in general, so I'm not quite sure it counts as a duplicate.

$(1,3)$ is an "[ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)". $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),\ldots\}$ is "the set of all ordered pairs of numbers in the set $\{1,2,3\}$". This set can be written with the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) as "$\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}$" or the [cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power) as "$\{1,2,3\}^2$".

$(3,1,2)$ is an "ordered triple" or an "[(ordered) tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) of length $3$" or "a $3$-tuple". The set of all such things could be denoted "$\{1,2,3\}^3$" or (more arguably) "$\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}$".

In general, what you're calling "combinations for the [set $S$] for a depth of $n$" would be $n$-tuples (even if $n$ is $1$ or $0$), and the set of them could be written $S^n$.

Your special case of the set being something finite $\{1,2,3\}$ comes up often enough that there are other words/notations that can help. [Wikipedia reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#n-tuples_of_m-sets) that in certain contexts, these tuples might be called "arrangements with repetition" or "[permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets)". Some texts on Combinatorics use a special notation like $[m]$ to denote the set $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, so that the set of $n$-tuples would simply by $[m]^n$ and the number of them would be $m^n$.

Comment: Can this terminology be applied to binary vectors? I'm trying to figure out the name for a "permutation depth" in this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661812/is-there-a-name-for-the-number-of-ones-in-a-binary-vector . If you think this terminology can be applied there too, I'd appreciate an answer.