# Terminology for number of zeros in a vector

Tags: terminology

What is the mathematical terminology if I want to express the number of zeros (or non-zero) elements in a vector?

There is a $l_0$ "[norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_p_=_0)" that counts non-zero elements of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^0$$
however it is a problematic function because we have to define $0^0=0$. Also it is not a norm but just called in quotes "norm".

Shall we use text to describe a zero-counting function $f(x)$? We could define without mathematical operators:

> $f(x)$ is the function that counts the number of $0$ in $x$

Comment: Also, what you call the $\ell^0$ norm is not, in fact, a norm.

Comment: There probably isn't a good name for this, because a vector is not, in general, a sequence of values. That is just the most common way of representing vectors, given a known basis.

Comment: I think that correcting codes use this kind of "norm" , you should check that

Comment: For a vector that's just 0s and 1s there are a bunch of possibilities here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661812

Comment: In the case there are not only 0s and 1s.

Comment: To avoid $0^0$ exactly, you can take limits: $$\lim_{p\to0^+}\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p,$$ noting that $0^p=0$ for $p>0$ (but not for $p<0$).